# Die you threadpoolexecutor

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a java.util.concurrent.Execution service - a single threaded thread pool executor. I submit certain tasks to it. If the task throws an unchecked exception the thread dies but the service ensures that a new thread is spawned and subsequent tasks are performed in that. However I do not want this feature and still want to use a threadPoolExecutor. i.e. I want the service to shutDownNow() if the task throws an unchecked exception.

What is the best way to achieve this? Would using a custom thread factory which restricts the number of threads spawned make good sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a ThreadPoolExecutor subclass and override the afterExecute method. The method has a throwable parameter that will be non-null if there was an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your `threadPoolExecutor` in an `ExecutorCompletionService`. Then continually `take()` from it, retrieving `Future`s. If `future.get()` throws an `Exception`, call `threadpoolexecutor.shutdown()`.

Comment: I found this very useful when running multiple threads using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor under JUnit when compared to overriding the afterExecute() method because the Throwable argument to that method was always null for some reason.